# How can I find the name of the Kernel and its version that is running in my phone?

Tags: nexus-5, kernel, 6.0-marshmallow, z4root

I had flashed Android 6.0 Marshmallow in My Nexus 5. As a [part of a rooting process](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/mra58k-root-for-android-6-0-marshmallow-update-84711/), I had to flash the kernel to allow SU binary to work.

All is fine and root works well.

Kernel is a intangible software component. How can I know the name and version of the kernel that I am using on my phone after installing it? I mean if I do not remember from where I downloaded the kernel or do not have the its ZIP file, are there any means with which I can find the kernel's name and its version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing, download an app called “terminal emulator” and open that terminal and invoke this command:

```
      $ uname  -a
```

It will show you your kernel version, and its name and other details.

Comment: Cool. In terminal emulator running in Marshmallow, the command option `-all` did not work.  It seems it is `uname -a` and that worked. Thanks. +1.

Comment: `uname -all` doesn't even work in my Slackware let alone in my Android. On which device did you test your command?

Answer (score 3):

Unless Marshmallow has some unnecessary native changes, you should be able to see the kernel version in many Android releases from  **Settings → About phone**.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

---

A command line way other than `uname -a` can be:

```
cat /proc/version
```

Output in my case is:

```
Linux version 3.4.107~AK.236.OPO.CM12.1 (ak@kernel) (gcc version 4.9.3 20150424 (prerelease) (UBERTC-4.9.3) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 30 08:37:49 CEST 2015
```

where,

- `Linux` -- Kernel name
- `3.4.107~AK.236.OPO.CM12.1` -- Kernel release
- `#1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 30 08:37:49 CEST 2015` -- Kernel version (I know it's odd)
- the rest is homework :)

Provided that you've root access or command executed using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) `dumpstate` can also show you what you want, but the rest of the output would be overwhelming.

---

Another alternative can be an app which can show system details, such as  [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) or [Droid Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkwired.droidinfo).

[image: IMG:]

Comment: My goodness - I feel kind of dump to miss the `About phone` page. In Marshmallow, it does show the kernel as it did in terminal emulator. +1